# cx_freeze does not find dependency packages

Tags: python, numpy, cx-freeze

I have significantly large python application, which I am trying to make in to a windows msi using cx_freeze.

Below is my script. The only way for me to find all the dependent packages is performing a build. The install the msi, execute the program and then python complains about a missing library. I then manually include them and it starts working.

Typically if you see some includes like "`numpy.linalg._umath_linalg`" was found only byt trial and error, becasue in the script we simply use `import numpy as Np` but cxfreeze doesnt pick up all dependencies during build. Is there a simple way of including all the modules without much trial and error?

```
build_exe_options = {"packages": ["PyQt4.QtCore",
                                  "PyQt4.QtGui",
                                  "glob",
                                  "time",
                                  "re",
                                  "getpass",
                                  "csv",
                                  "numpy.lib.format",
                                  "numpy.linalg",
                                  "numpy.linalg._umath_linalg",
                                  "numpy.linalg.lapack_lite",
                                  "scipy.io.matlab.streams",
                                  "scipy.integrate",
                                  "scipy.integrate.vode",
                                  "scipy.sparse.linalg.dsolve.umfpack",
                                  "scipy.integrate.lsoda",
                                  "scipy.special",
                                  "scipy.special._ufuncs_cxx",
                                  "scipy.sparse.csgraph._validation",
                                  "matplotlib.pyplot",
                                  "matplotlib.backends",
                                  "matplotlib.backends.backend_qt4agg",
                                  "sys"],
                     "excludes": ["pyzmq",
                                  "wxpython",
                                  "tables",
                                  "zmq",
                                  "wx",
                                  "Tkinter"]}
```

Comment: cx_Freeze should automatically detect modules that are imported, and include them without you having to specify them. Also, if you just specify `numpy` in `packages`, it should include all subpackages and modules from numpy, without you specifying them individually. To save you making and installing an msi each time, use `build_exe` in place of `bdist_msi` until you've got a working exe.